# Using pipe symbol and "print" in Windows

Tags: shell, dos, pipe

I am trying to make a shell script work in Windows. Sorry but I'm not very experienced in Windows (or even that much in shell to be honest). The script works well except for this one line:

```
print "9\n0\n1\n5\n0\n0\n\n" | /usr/ts23/mm_util
```

The `mm_util` is an interactive utility that takes numbers as input. It chooses selection 9 first, then 0, then 1, etc. I've changed the path to use the utility, which has an identical interface in Windows but the output is just the first screen. The "9" input isn't entered, and because of this the output (that is parsed) is incorrect. How can I change this so that the "9" is entered on the first screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that does not require a file. It works on the command line:

```
(for %N in (9 0 1 5 0 0 "") do @echo(%~N)|c:\Users\ts23\mm_util
```

The `""` is to get an empty line in the output, as you had in your original question. Your answer does not have the blank line.

The `%~N` notation strips enclosing quotes from the value.

The `echo(` is non-intuitive syntax that can reliably print a blank line, in case `%~N` expands to nothing.

Don't forget to double the percents if you put the code in a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put that nine-linebreak-zero-stuff in a text file, and then execute `print textfile.txt | /usr/ts23/mm_util`

And bear in mind that Windows uses the pre-UNIX convention that the linebreak is `CR LF`, not just `LF`.

Comment: I have tried entering `9\r\n` `9\n` and just `9` into a test.txt file and tried your command but unfortunately, it still isn't working, same behavior as before. Only the first screen is shown.

Answer (score 1):

The way I got the output I wanted was by using this:

> C:\Users\ts23\mm_util < test.txt

And then just put the following inside test.txt

```
9
0
1
5
0
0
```

The output I got was what I needed, hopefully this will help someone trying to do something like this in the future.